# Changing from Activity to fragment in Android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using a beginner in android studio development. I am trying to change my activity code to fragment code. So far I managed however, I found a difficulty in this piece of code:

```
public void logout(){

        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(i);
        ((HomeActivity) context).finish();
    }
```

Basically I want to change `HomeActivity` with a fragment which resides in my mainActivity, and I have tried to replace `HomeActivity` with `getActivity()` but it marks it as invalid since this java file is not in the fragment but in a separate java file

Fragment code:

```
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();//getting the info
private TextView name, email;
private Button btn_logout;

SessionManager sessionManager;
String getId;
private static String URL_READ = "http://192.168.1.123:81/android_register_login/read_detail.php";
private static String URL_EDIT = "http://192.168.1.123:81/android_register_login/edit_detail.php";

private Menu action;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);

    sessionManager = new SessionManager(getActivity());
    sessionManager.checkLogin();

    Button btn_logout = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);
    btn_logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sessionManager.logout();
            Intent logout = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(logout);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: I'm unable to understand what you trying to do from your code, why you don't try to follow one of millions tutorials on this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use startActivity() directly from fragment, so you can use getActivity().startActivity() or getContext.startActivity(); I'm not sure, so try them both. 
In addition, provide error, I'll be able to say exact problem)) 
Moreover, try not to use functions from inside of activities, better  to put them into another class.
And if u r gonna to use something from activity, learn about interfaces)) 
Hope it helps))

Comment: The problem is in the first piece of code since I am trying to change the homeActivity to a fragment i.e I dont know with what to replace the line of code: ((HomeActivity) context).finish();

Comment: Use getActivity.finish()

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try